# SOLR Search not returing results

Tags: solr

I am setting SOLR search engine to my website. I have installed SOLR and modifed the SOLRconfig.xml and SChema.xml according to my requirements. Now when i use search all results returing 0 matching. Is anything else to be configured other than this. Kindly advice.

Thanks

Comment: Plz show exact query, schema.xml, etc. More details!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you haven't mentioned that you indexed anything to the solr. So if there is no index, it will return 0 results. Index some data and it will work

Comment: Thank for your reply. I was given only Schema.xml and SolrConfig.xml. I have configured it. Explain more about indexing or any ref link would be helpful

Comment: i suggest you to go through this https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Indexing+and+Basic+Data+Operations Please accept the answer if it helped you in someway.

Comment: but we using SOLR 1.3